# cerrar session automaticamente en laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-8

Quisiera poder programar que vencido el tiempo de session, este automaticamente me redirija al login.

Tengo una ruta con el middleware AUTH

para validar que solo me deje entrar si el usuario esta autenticado, y este funciona bien.

ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/usuario', [App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController::class,'index'])->name('usuario.index')->middleware('auth');
```

Si intento ingresar, a esa ruta - url, sin haberme logueado, este no me deja entrar, y todo ok.

cuando me registro e ingreso, me deja sin problema.

he configurado la variable session para efectos de prueba en 1 minuto.

```
config/session.php


    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 1),

    'expire_on_close' => false,
```

y tambien he modificado el archivo .env

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=1
```

adicional dentro de mi controllador he agregado el constructor de authenticacion.

```
UsuarioController // 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

pero pasado el tiempo, dejando la vista abierta, esta sigue abierta.
si le doy click a cualquier otro vinculo, o a esta misma vista, o le doy F5, o refresco.
efectivamente, este me pide contraseña de nuevo, pero quiero que al pasar el tiempo, este automaticamente me saque, y me deje en login.

¿como puedo hacer esto? ¿deberia funcionar asi por defecto laravel y estoy haciendo algo mal? muchas gracias!

Comment: Necesitas (*al menos así lo interpreto*) por ejemplo una llamada AJAX para que el backend pueda evaluar el factor de tiempo y en caso de superarlo cerrar la sesión

Comment: Efictivamente, no puedes hacerlo sólo con laravel (que corre en el lado servidor). Tendrías que implementar javascript para poder hacerlo en el navegador (el lado cliente). Otra opción sería con un [WebSocket](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting).

Comment: la sesion esta expirando bien lo que pasa es que la data que tienes en la pantalla es data del cliente y laravel corre en el servidor, para que se haga un llamado al servidor debes hacer una peticion, lo facil que puedes hacer es una funcion settime con 1 segundo adicional al tiempo que expira la sesion, que haga un location reload, como no va encontrar respuesta del servidor se va ir al login